html audio player progress bar style
A simple question,
Is there a way to change the background color of the HTML5 audio progress bar using CSS and WebKit Properties

Custom styling of Safari (WebKit) <audio> elements is not possible, because WebKit renders <audio> elements using Shadow DOM and encapsulated CSS that cannot be overridden by design:

